# Ruby On Rails SQLite errors when creating new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I've been working with ruby recently, I really like the language and have been picking it up really quick I decided it was time to try and work with the Rails framework. When I try to create a new project my typing

```
rails new first-site
```

I get the following errors I've spent hours Googling it and haven't found any similar result

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
--enable-local
--disable-local


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3 /gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then run the     gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8' and get similar errors. 
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install sqlite

That is where the

```
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite-devel'
```

If you have another db setup like postgres you can run it with the database switch

```
rails new myapp --database=postgresql
```

Comment: I'm using Kali linux, so neither of those work. I tried it with apt-get install that didn't work either. @emcanes

Answer (score 0):

I found out I was missing developer dependencies when trying to use the MySQL gem. All is fixed now :)